# What can we say about the rank of a commutator?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider two $n\times n$ (hermitian) matrices $A$ and $B$. It is well know that they share a common eigenbasis if they commute, i.e. if $[A,B]=AB-BA=0$. I am interested in common eigenvectors in case $[A,B] \neq 0$.

The zero matrix has rank 0. It is tempting to try to read off the number of orthogonal common eigenvectors $m$ from the rank of the commutator as

$m = n - \text{rk}[A,B]$.

Is this statement true? If yes, where can I find a proof? If no, is there any other connection between the rank of a commutator and the eigenspaces of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: A first step is looking at this result: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132909/rank-of-the-commutator-of-linear-transformations?rq=1

Comment: If $[A,B]$ commutes with $A$, then it is nilpotent, so has not full rank, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299640/ab-ba-is-a-nilpotent-matrix-if-it-commutes-with-a).